# mysql query for find category

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got a product table like this

```
id   |   name   | category 
--------------------------
1    |   name1  |  2,1,5,8,9
2    |   name2  |  2,1
3    |   name3  |  5,8
```

And I got a category table like this

```
id   |   catname   
----------------
1    |   cat_name1  
2    |   cat_name2  
5    |   cat_name3 
8    |   cat_name3 
9    |   cat_name3
```

Each product can have multiple categories. Categories associated with that product are saved in a row named "category" in product table as "1,5,8,7", Where each represent category table's id.

Now I want to display all the products came under a specific category.

I am little bit confused with the query to handle this.

And is this the correct format for saving such type of data ? 
Please advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add an extra Table for product-category mapping.

```
SELECT p.name 
 FROM products p 
   JOIN product_category pc ON  p.id=pc.prod_id 
   JOIN Category c ON c.id = pc.categ_id
 WHERE c.name='Category'
```

Answer (score 4):

An assocation table: product-category would simplify the query you want.

Assuming a ProductCategory table with columns (prod_id, cat_id), your query (based on the name of a category) would be:

```
  SELECT p.name FROM products p,product_category pc ,category c
  WHERE c.name='your_categ' 
  AND c.id = pc.categ_id
  AND p.id = pc.prod_id
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not correct way to store the product categories, the tables are not normalized according to 3NF. Since a product can belong to many categories and a category is assigned to many products, you must have a M:N (many-to-many) table, eg. `products_categories(prod_id, categ_id)` and search this table instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE 
    category LIKE "ID,%" OR 
    category LIKE "%,ID,%" OR 
    category LIKE "%,ID"
```

Above query should work - beware of performance issues, as others suggested linking table is the only way.